# An equation defined by norm

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, integral-extensions

Let $f$ be an Eisenstein polynomial of degree $n$ and the prime $p$. $\alpha$ is a root of $f$. Let $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=K$, Prove that for any $\gamma\in O_K$, there exist $a\in \mathbb{Z}$, such that 
$$N_{K/ {\mathbb{Q}}}(\gamma)\equiv a^n\ \ (mod\ p) $$

Comment: $p$ is completely ramified, so $\gamma \equiv a \bmod {\mathfrak p}$..

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer  You get this from the condition or the conclusion？

Comment: If a prime is completely ramified, the prime ideal above $p$ has degree $1$, so every element is congruent to a rational integer.